# What score value is considered acceptable when using Vina Autodock tool for molecular docking simulations?

Tags: docking

What score value is considered acceptable when using Vina Autodock tool for molecular docking simulations?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "Depends". But the best thing is always to look at what you ended up with and do some triaging before buying/synthesising anything. By triaging I mean filtering by its properties (*.e.g.* [Lipinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipinski%27s_rule_of_five), reactivity, synthetic feasibility *etc.* —discussed in [this Bioinfo SE question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/12971/generate-ligands-candidates-based-on-protein-shape/12975)).

### Score

Regardless of docking software used, a forcefield free-energy score is a result of the scoring function used and of the properties of the molecule —including VENA which uses a hybrid score function.

This score is *not*, but generally is set up to try to match, the actual phys-chem one.
[Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) is measured in kcal/mol (or less commonly in kJ/mol). A hydrogen bond is about 2 kcal/mol, a π-π bond 1 kcal/mol and a salt bridge 3. The average energy of a collision of RT water molecules is 0.6 kcal/mol.

Therefore, if you dock multiple compounds (virtual library screen, VLS) you sort by free energy to see the strongest binders and consider the top ones.
However, a catch is that this will be biased by MW.

Also, it is useful to score the hits with a different program (say Gold or ICM-dock).

### Ligand Efficiency

A variant metric that is employed when your hits vary in size and when they are over a given size (*e.g.* not fragments under 200 Da) is [Ligand Efficiency (LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligand_efficiency)), which is the ratio of your score over the number of heavy atoms ([ref](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrd4163)).

### Single compound

If you have a single compound and want to know if it binds acceptably, then this is a length-of-a-piece-of-string question as every compound has an affinity constant to a given protein, except most may be beyond their solubility. Initial hits will have µM affinity, while a lead will have nM affinity. However, a KD is not a ∆G and depends on your protein.